# Error when creating a network namespace inside a docker container. error: mount --make-shared /run/netns failed: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, docker-network

I'm getting an error when creating a network namespace inside a docker container saying permission denied.

```
command  
ip netns add red
```

```
error
mount --make-shared /run/netns failed: Permission denied
```

I am running an image ubuntu:20.10 and tried by adding specific capabilities to the container and it did not help.

```
docker run -it --rm --name=ubuntu --cap-add CAP_SYS_ADMIN --cap-add NET_ADMIN ubuntu:20.10
apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools && apt-get install -y iproute2
```

Even after adding all capabilities issue remain same.

```
docker run -it --rm --name=ubuntu --cap-add ALL ubuntu:20.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--cap-add` & `--privileged` are not same.
Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Issue is sorted by running the container with privilege. Capabilities seems not required for adding network namespace.

```
docker run -d --name=<name> --network=none --privileged <image>:<tag>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The other answer suggests adding `--privileged`, but note that adding `--privileged` effectively removes all security features. If you are uncomfortable with this, you might prefer an approach that gives the container access only to what it needs.

The root cause is that Docker's [default apparmor profile](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/20.10/profiles/apparmor/template.go) contains the rule [`deny mount`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/791d8ab87747169b4cbfcdf2fd57c81952bae6d5/profiles/apparmor/template.go#L44) which prevents `mount` from working inside Docker containers, which is what is causing the error message `mount --make-shared /run/netns failed: Permission denied`.

You can confirm that this is the root cause by observing what happens if you add `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` to your command, which disables apparmor but preserves other security features. Notice that the `mount` command succeeds:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --name=ubuntu \
  --cap-add CAP_SYS_ADMIN --cap-add NET_ADMIN \
  --security-opt apparmor=unconfined \
  ubuntu
apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools iproute2
ip netns add red # succeeds
```

If you don't want to fully opt out of apparmor, you can create a custom apparmor profile, then load it with `apparmor_parser -r -W path/to/your/profile` and then apply it to your `docker` command using `--security-opt apparmor=your-profile-name`. You can create a custom apparmor profile by copying Docker's template and then tweaking it to suit your needs.

At the time of writing, [Docker does not have an easy way to show the apparmor profile it is currently using](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33060), but you can [look at the source template](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/20.10/profiles/apparmor/template.go) and then expand the template manually (by following the template logic).

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/